# Problema com AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, lista, diretório

estou tentando percorrer todos os arquivos do diretório C:\ do meu computador. Antes estava usando a biblioteca IO, porém tava dando uns problemas e agora estou usando a NIO, Com a NIO está dando tudo certo, estou percorrendo todos os arquivos do diretório e de suas sub-pastas, o problema é que existem alguns diretórios com acesso negado, quando o código vai percorrendo e encontra essas pasta com acesso negado, ele retorna um exceção AccessDeniedException, até ao normal. O problema ocorre quando vou usar um try...catch para "pular" essas exceções e continuar percorrendo, mas em vez disso ele meio que para de percorrer outras pastas. Alguém pode dar uma luz

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Path;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;
   import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
   import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

   public class PercorrendoArquivosComSubPasta {
      public static void main(String args[])  throws IOException {

      Path source = Paths.get("C:\\");

      try {
         Files.walkFileTree(source, new MyFileVisitor());
      } catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }

  class MyFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

     public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes){

        System.out.println("Nome do arquivo:" + path.getFileName()); return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
     }


      public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes){
         System.out.println("----------Nome do diretório:" + path + "----------");
         return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu descobrir a solução, basta implementar o método visitFileFailed na classe MyFileVisitor. [Aqui a solução](https://github.com/joelhenrique2000/JAVA-IO/blob/master/src/br/com/algoritmos/PercorrendoArquivosComSubPasta.java)